# Mac - Force closing terminals without reopening them

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

This command closes all terminal windows

```
ps aux | grep -i terminal | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill -9
```

Afterwards, when I click the terminal icon, all of the terminal windows reopen.

The reason I'm doing this is to close any terminals when I leave the office, and then in the morning have one fresh terminal (without restarting) when I open the terminal app.

Is there a way to programmatically way to force close all terminals and have them not reopen when I activate the terminal app.

Comment: side-note: This should be `pkill -i terminal`

Comment: Doesn't Cmd-Q quit Terminal without saving the windows? Why do you need a script?

Comment: By the end of the day unfortunately I have around 20 terminal windows open. So I would have to Cmd-Q through all of them.

Comment: @ClickThisNick, Are the Terminal windows running a process? Is this why you feel you need to force quit them? Otherwise, **⌘Q** will instantly close all Terminal windows at once that do not have an active process running.

Comment: Do you have the Terminal Dock Tile set to Keep in Dock? If so and if you've used the command line shown in your OP to close all Terminal windows... you can simple hold the Shift key down while clicking the Terminal Dock Tile and only one Terminal window should open.

Comment: Yea some are running processes. But yea that shift trick is a good one, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state information is saved in `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState/` so you can delete that directory after closing Terminal.

As mentioned in the comments, the `pkill` and `pgrep` utilities are used for finding processes by name. There shouldn't be a need for `-9` but I've included it anyway to match your original code. We use the `-a` argument to ensure that ancestors of the `pkill` process are considered, and I've limited it to processes controlled by the current user, in case you share your machine.

```
#!/bin/bash
pkill -9 -a -U "$UID" Terminal
rm -rf ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState/
```